# Cannot use another method in fetch method with React Query

Tags: reactjs, class, react-query

I have abstracted some logic for fetching data into its own service.

```
import type { Todo } from './Todo';

class TodoService {
  private async secretFetch() {
    const todos = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/');
    return (await todos.json()) as Todo[];
  }

  async fetchTodos() {
    const todos = await this.secretFetch();
    return todos;
  }
}

const todoService = new TodoService();

export default todoService;
```

I would like to use this method as a parameter for `useQuery`, but I noticed that the query fails when the method calls another method inside my class.

```
export default function App() {
  const { data: todos, isLoading } = useQuery('todos', todoService.fetchTodos);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <p> Loading </p>;
  }

  if (todos.length === 0) {
    return <p> There are no todos </p>;
  }

  return (
    <ul>
      {todos.map((todo) => (
        <li> {todo.title} </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Here's an example in Stack blitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-5uxsz5?file=App.tsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've lose `this` reference

Either create an anonymous function

```
const { data: todos, isLoading } = useQuery('todos', () => todoService.fetchTodos());
```

or bind

```
const { data: todos, isLoading } = useQuery('todos', todoService.fetchTodos.bind(todoService));
```

Comment: I see, I need to read up on `this`. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

`this` in the `fetchTodos` points to the wrong *context*.

Either transform the `fetchTodos` into an *arrow function*:

```
fetchTodos = async () => {
   const todos = await this.secretFetch();
   return todos;
}
```

or set the `secretFetch` as a static method and access it:

```
class TodoService {
  private static async secretFetch() {
    ...
  }

  async fetchTodos() {
    const todos = await TodoService.secretFetch();
    return todos;
  }
}
```